# Hiding and showing text in React

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I'm having troubles wrapping my head around this. I'm trying to show/hide text inside one of my components, but I'm not able to do it. I get `I was clicked!` message so I know the function is being passed down. What am I missing?

Do I also need to declare a `visibility` CSS declaration, maybe that's what I'm missing?

**SnippetList.jsx**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import Snippet from './snippet'
import { Snippets } from '../../../api/collections/snippets.js'


class SnippetList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { visible: false }
        this.toggleVisible = this.toggleVisible.bind(this);
    }

    toggleVisible() {
        this.setState( { visible: !this.state.visible } )
        console.log('I was clicked');
    }

    renderSnippets() {

        return this.props.snippets.map( (snippet) => (
            <Snippet 
            key={snippet._id} 
            title={snippet.title}
            content={snippet.content}
            onClick={this.toggleVisible}
            />
        ));
    }

    render() {
        const snippets = Snippets.find({}).fetch({});

        return (
            snippets.length > 0 
            ?
            <ul>{this.renderSnippets()}</ul>
            : 
            <p>No Snippets at this time</p>
        )
    }   
}

SnippetList.propTypes = {
    snippets: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
}

export default createContainer(() => {
    Meteor.subscribe('snippets');

    return {
        snippets: Snippets.find({}).fetch()
    };
}, SnippetList);
```

**Snippet.jsx**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'

export default class Snippet extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const visible = this.props.toggleVisible
        return (
            <article>
                <header>
                    <h1 className='Snippet-title'>{this.props.title}</h1>
                </header>
                <div className={visible ? 'show' : 'hidden'} onClick={this.props.onClick}>
                    <p className='Snippet-content'>{this.props.content}</p>
                </div>
            </article>
        )
    }
}

Snippet.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    content: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    // toggleVisible: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

Comment: do you have rules for these 'show' and 'hidden' classes in your css?

Comment: No I do not, maybe that's the problem?im getting confused into how to toggle them

Comment: Just added them but still seeing the problem. They do not hide. `.show { visibility: visible;}` `.hidden{visibility: hidden;}

Comment: do they appear in class atributes of rendered component?

Comment: The  `show` yes now I just need to toggle it to `hidden` when I click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is you aren't passing the hide part as a prop.

in Snippet you do `const visible = this.props.toggleVisible` but... toggleVisible isn't passed to your Snippet component thus its always undefined

```
return this.props.snippets.map( (snippet) => (
    <Snippet 
    key={snippet._id} 
    title={snippet.title}
    content={snippet.content}
    onClick={this.toggleVisible}
    />
));
```

add toggleVisible... aka change to this.

```
return this.props.snippets.map( (snippet) => (
    <Snippet 
        key={snippet._id} 
        title={snippet.title}
        content={snippet.content}
        toggleVisible={this.state.visible}
        onClick={this.toggleVisible}
    />
));
```

you should probably also bind your `renderSnippets` this to the class as well... meaning add this to your constructor `this.renderSnippets = this.renderSnippets.bind(this);`

---

Now to talk about your code, why are you rendering a `<ul>` as the parent of a `<article>` ? the child of a ul should be a `<li>` I would refactor your components to be more like this.

```
class SnippetList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { visible: false };
        this.toggleVisible = this.toggleVisible.bind(this);
        this.renderSnippets = this.renderSnippets.bind(this);
    }

    toggleVisible() {
        this.setState( { visible: !this.state.visible } )
        console.log('I was clicked');
    }

    renderSnippets() {
        return this.props.snippets.map( (snippet) => (
            <Snippet 
                key={snippet._id} 
                title={snippet.title}
                content={snippet.content}
                toggleVisible={this.state.visible}
                onClick={this.toggleVisible}
            />
        ));
    }

    render() {
        const snippets = Snippets.find({}).fetch({});
        return (
            snippets.length > 0 
              ?  <ul>{this.renderSnippets()}</ul>
              :  <p>No Snippets at this time</p>
        )
    }   
}


export default class Snippet extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {toggleVisible: visible} = this.props;
        return (
            <li>
                <article>
                    <header>
                        <h1 className="Snippet-title">{this.props.title}</h1>
                    </header>
                    <div onClick={this.props.onClick}>
                        <p className={visible ? 'show Snippet-content' : 'hidden Snippet-content'}>{this.props.content}</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </li>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: made all the above changes. We are getting there. The all appear hidden now,  but cannot make them to show when clicked.  Inside my  `render` on the  `snippet` component I have `const visible = this.props.toggleVisible` and on the `return` ` <div className={visible ? 'show' : 'hidden'} onClick=...`

Comment: @D_S the problem is most likely because you are making the element that you do the click on hidden with the hide class.. so subsequent clicks wouldn't show it because the click event is not fired. you should put the show / hide class on a parent. dont hide the element that has the click event on it. hide a child with the content in it

Comment: Mother frigging Christ. That worked. Thanks guys. I need to brush up on my react basics. Any other good resources besides the main docs to recommend?

Comment: If you want I can give you a crash course sometime on how to do it :) I've been using react for somewhere around 4 years, so I know a bit about it. how are you doing data flow? are you using any frameworks like redux or flux?

Comment: also, the click event on the parent isn't a react thing, its just a css / html thing

Comment: I would love a crash course. Please I'm trying to build a blog in react and meteor. But I'm very rusty. No not using flux nor redux since I'm still having problems understanding how react works. I'm usually free during the weekends man if you have time or late in the evening. Would you like to take this to a chat? I'm on my way to work but will be at the office in about 1hr

Comment: @D_S Sure, Its midnight for me right now so we may need to work around a schedule. you can email me johnruddell@gmail.com. but I would recommend you read up on how to incorporate redux in your app. its a great way to implement one way data binding. http://marmelab.com/blog/2015/11/27/meteor-webpack-react-redux.html

Comment: thanks man. I'll read up on that and send you an email in the next couple of hours